# JavaScript a function that returns a changing value on every call

Tags: javascript, function, return-value

I'm trying to write  a function that when called will return take into account the previous call to it.  I'm new to JavaScript so I just want to make sure it can be done.  I want to store the changing value in a mutable variable.

```
var formatPrint = function(orig, changed){
    return "Started with "+orig+" now is "+changed; 
}

var adder = function(orig){
        var changed = orig;
        return function(){return printer(orig, (changed+5))};
}
```

I'm calling the function as follows:

```
var orig10 = adder(10);
orig10();
```

Returns Started with 10 now is 15

```
orig10();
```

Returns Started with 10 now is 15

```
orig10();
```

Returns Started with 10 now is 15

should return
Returns Started with 10 now is 15
Returns Started with 10 now is 20
Returns Started with 10 now is 25

Sorry If my code should be inputed into the forum I was having issues doing it. I'm a nooby.. Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [+=](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators)?

```
var adder = function(orig){
    var changed = orig;
    return function(){return printer(orig, (changed+=5))};
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/3T72G/

Comment: Thanks! It works as long as I'm adding, now lets says I wanted to do multiple things to it perhaps.  (((changed+=5)*5)%5).  Is it possible to do this with an equal operator??

Comment: well, you could do, for example, `changed+=5;changed*=5;changed%5`, but no, you can't combine it into one statement like that. If you just wish to use `=` without `+=`, you can use the verbose equivalent: `changed=changed+5;`, for example

Comment: Also, welcome to SO! If you find an answer answers your question, click the small check below the vote count and arrows near the upper left of the answer to "accept" the answer

Comment: Thanks for the help.  On to the next JavaScript issue!!

Answer (score 1):

Reading your question and comments, it seems like you are trying to create some sort of [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) with which you can perform certain math functions and have it format a particular string when requested. If so, then you may be looking to do something like this.

Javascript

```
function MyConstructor(orig) {
    this.orig = this.current = orig;
}

MyConstructor.prototype.toString = function () {
    return "Started with " + this.orig + " now is " + this.current;
};

MyConstructor.prototype.add = function (value) {
    this.current += value;

    return this;
};

MyConstructor.prototype.subtract = function (value) {
    this.current -= value;

    return this;
};

MyConstructor.prototype.multiply = function (value) {
    this.current *= value;

    return this;
};

MyConstructor.prototype.divide = function (value) {
    this.current /= value;

    return this;
};

MyConstructor.prototype.mod = function (value) {
    this.current %= value;

    return this;
};

var orig10 = new MyConstructor(10);

console.log(orig10.toString());
orig10.add(5).multiply(5).mod(2);
console.log(orig10.toString());
```

Output

```
Started with 10 now is 10
Started with 10 now is 1
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/qLzU9/)

Comment: I was working on a fiddle very similar to this. I agree w/ this as an answer